# creating new SKSpriteNode vs using a copy of a SKSpriteNode

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm looking for ways to improve the performance of my game. In my game, the boss will cast 16 fireballs at once (at different angles). My current code is to create a SKSpriteNode for each fireball, and repeat the process 16 times. I can improve the performance by dispatching the creation process to a different thread and then add the sprite back to main thread once it's created. This way I don't see a noticeable lag in the gameplay. 
However, I'm thinking that will it improve the performance even more if I cache the first fireball sprite after it's being created and then use .copy() 15 times to create the rest of the fireballs?
ultimately, I'm trying understand is using .copy() on a SKSpriteNode as expensive as creating new one?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy is a little less expensive, but not much.  It doesn't need to access any IO to grab things like the texture since you already have it in memory.

Now the way you are designing your game,  you should not be constantly recreating fireballs.  You should create a pool of them, and constantly recycle them.  This way you only have to create them once during the loading portion of your game, and you are not wasting precious cycles on redundant work.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I've heard of the concept of object pooling, but not sure how to implement it. For starters, if the boss casts 16 fireballs at once and might be casting 30 times before he dies, that's 16 * 30 = 480 fireballs. So do I need to create 500 fireballs in the loading phase? Sorry for the silly assumption as I don't know how object pooling works. Can you please show me how it's implemented. Thanks so much.

Comment: The boss casts 3 rounds of fireballs, each round consists of 16 fireballs, there is a pause of 0.3sec in between each round. So at least 32 fireballs on screen at one time.

Comment: Then you need at least 32 fireballs in your pool.  You make a set of 32 fireballs, when you need it, you remove it from the set, and when the fireball is done, you place it back into the set.

Comment: You can then do some advance processing like if your pool ever gets lower than 10%, use a background thread to add more fireballs into the pool to increase the number available.

Comment: Great! thanks for the pointers. However, I'm just curious as how much performance increase can I get from using object pooling where I need to constantly replenish the pool with 32 fireballs instead of creating 16 of them when needed, both done in a background thread?

Comment: you are not replenishing,  You are using the same 32 fireballs over and over.  This means no creation during gameplay, You are only using a couple CPU cycles to move memory and reset some variables.

Comment: I see. this is definitely much more efficient! Thanks again!